# When will the US open its borders to Europe again?

Tags: usa, europe, covid-19

I'm 54, from italy and i have a partner in the US. We are not married.

On the white house website it says:

"On January 31, 2020, I issued Proclamation 9984 (Suspension of Entry as Immigrants and Nonimmigrants of Persons Who Pose a Risk of Transmitting 2019 Novel Coronavirus and Other Appropriate Measures To Address This Risk). ...".

One year has passed and still nothing has changed. I haven't seen my partner for more than a year and I'm really tired of waiting. Is there a planned end date for this? When will i be able to travel to the US again?

Comment: We don't know. Even where restrictions have been eased they have often been reintroduced. Only once the pandemic starts to ease worldwide can we expect border restrictions to be lifted. The availability of vaccines will help with this, but even though the UK has approved a vaccine today, it will take time for other countries to follow and for significant quantities of vaccine to be available.

Comment: Since this is a proclamation of the president, the next president need to revoke this. Very uncertain when this will happen. Your partner is US citizen? Then he can travel to Italy back and forth I presume. So why not invite him?

Comment: No realistic assessment can be given presently. Possibly in April a **cautious** estimate can be made, depending on the amount of peaple have been vaccinated by then and how long it will take until a 60-70% coverage can be achieved. When the last point is achieved, then most of the restrictions will probably be removed completely with a reduction being phase in beforehand. At present there are simply to many unknowns to give a more precise answer.

Comment: Nor can you even assume that a significant portion of the population will *want* to be vaccinated. As usual, disinformation spreads faster than truth.

Comment: As others have said, we don't know. There is strong pressure from a lot of groups, especially airlines, to open things up. The new administration may remain very cautious and indeed wait for the pandemic to fizzle with widespread vaccination, or they could replace the current ban with testing or other similar protocols (as other countries have done).

Comment: @WeatherVane That too will be one of the unknown factors in the equation

Comment: @MarkJohnson, yes, that is why I wrote it.

Comment: Note that the current proclamation already has an exemption for "_any alien whose entry would not pose a significant risk of introducing, transmitting, or spreading the virus, as determined by the Secretary of Health and Human Services, through the CDC Director or his designee_". So the CDC may say "as long as they get tested, or have been vaccinated, or have antibodies, or whatever other criteria, we're OK with them".

Comment: It might also depend on when *you* get vaccinated, and that in turn depends on how the Italian government choose to prioritise different parts of their population. And I guess most non-Italians don't have time to care about that. But it's just one tiny piece of the puzzle of things that make this question unanswerable.

Comment: You can meet up with your partner by flying to Turkey, spending two weeks there, then flying to the US. A minor annoyance but travel is possible.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a planned end date for this?

No

> When will i be able to travel to the US again?

Sorry, no one knows.

We are in the middle of a global pandemic and no one has a good play back book for this. On the minus side, infection rates and spreading is spiking in many countries, on the up side a few vaccines have been already developed and early test results are encouraging.

Best guess at this point is that travel will (and should) be severely restricted until the vaccines are widely available and significant immunity has been developed.

Comment: and heaven forbid another, different, virus happens.

Comment: we are lucky, the virus is not too strong, otherwise we would be really doomed.